# How to populate the sub-documents returned after aggregate lookup in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following three schemas in mongodb.

```
const A = new Schema({
  labelA: String
})

const B = new Schema({
  labelB: String
  refToA: {Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'A'}
  refToCArray: [{Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'C'}]
})

const C = new Schema({
  labelC: String
})
```

I run following aggregation query in A to attach a field called 'BCollection' which contains records from B matching the id of A.

```
const ACollection = await A.aggregate([
  { $match: { labelA: 'LabelA1' } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'B',
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: 'refToA',
      as: 'BCollection',
    },
  },
])
```

My problem is that the attached B documents contain Id of C in 'refToCArray' field. I want to 'populate' or replace those ids with the actual contents from C. How do I do that.?

Example:

```
// Documents in A:
{_id: 'A_id1', labelA: 'LabelA1'}
{_id: 'A_id2', labelA: 'LabelA2'}

// Documents in B: 
{_id: 'B_id1', labelB: 'LabelB1', refToA: 'A_id1', refToCArray: ['C_id1']}
{_id: 'B_id2', labelB: 'LabelB2', refToA: 'A_id1', refToCArray: ['C_id1']}
{_id: 'B_id3', labelB: 'LabelB3', refToA: 'A_id1', refToCArray: ['C_id1']}
{_id: 'B_id4', labelB: 'LabelB4', refToA: 'A_id2', refToCArray: ['C_id1']}

// Documents in C
C1 {_id: 'C_id1', labelC: 'LabelC'}
```

The above query returns the following:

```
[{
  _id: 'A_id1',
  labelA: 'LabelA1'
  BCollection: [
    {_id: 'B_id1', labelB: 'LabelB1', refToA: 'A_id1', refToCArray: ['C_id1']},
    {_id: 'B_id2', labelB: 'LabelB2', refToA: 'A_id1', refToCArray: ['C_id1']},
    {_id: 'B_id3', labelB: 'LabelB3', refToA: 'A_id1', refToCArray: ['C_id1']}
  ]
}]
```

The query so far i good but refToCArray contains list of Ids: C_id1. I want to get results as below:

```
  [{
      _id: 'A_id1',
      labelA: 'LabelA1'
      BCollection: [
        {_id: 'B_id1', labelB: 'LabelB1', refToA: 'A_id1', refToCArray: [{_id: 'C_id1', labelC: 'LabelC'}]},
        {_id: 'B_id2', labelB: 'LabelB2', refToA: 'A_id1', refToCArray: [{_id: 'C_id1', labelC: 'LabelC'}]},
        {_id: 'B_id3', labelB: 'LabelB3', refToA: 'A_id1', refToCArray: [{_id: 'C_id1', labelC: 'LabelC'}]}
      ]
    }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
db.A.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "B",
            let: { refToA: "$_id" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: { $eq: ["$refToA", "$$refToA"] }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: "C",
                        localField: "refToCArray",
                        foreignField: "_id",
                        as: "refToCArray"
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "BCollection"
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Could you please look at this related question? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66489333/how-to-populate-deeply-nested-array-of-ids-after-aggregate-lookup-in-mongodb